# C# помогите с Form

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, form

Я создал копию формы Form1.cs и назвал новую форму Form2 и при каждой сборке программы Form2 становится обратно такой же как и Form1 а мне надо только скопировать Form1 в Form2 и изменить Form2

и еще я не могу изменять никак Form2 и эти квадраты еще...

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fiUH.jpg

---

Я добавляю новую форму выбираю производная форма
после выбираю форму Form1
и создается копия Form2 на скрине у меня она уже создана

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне нужно изменить эту копию под себя
но она не дает себя изменит
как мне сделать копию которую я смог бы изменить

Comment: Что значит Form2 стает такой же как Form1? В дизайнере стает такой же, или во время выполнения программы?

Comment: А почему Вы тут картинки не прикрепили? Опишите конкретнее, что не так, не понятна суть Вашего вопроса.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Производная форма" - это форма унаследованная от выбранной в мастере.

Обратите внимание на то, что заголовок класса `Form2` у вас выглядит примерно так:

```
public partial class Form2 : DatingSimulator.Form1
```

Вот эта добавка после `:` в имени класса и говорит о том, что форма унаследована от `Form1`. В отличие от форм созданных обычным способом, которые наследуются от библиотечного класса `Form`, заголовок которых выглядит так:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
```

Наследование в ООП вообще и C# в частности - строго расширяющее, это значит что вы не можете удалить что либо унаследованное от предка.

"Производная форма" применяется тогда, когда у вас есть реализация некоторой базовой формы, которая содержит только общие для всех форм элементы и код. Тогда вы можете создавать производные формы, чтобы не дублировать этот код, а добавлять только нужные в конкретной форме элементы и код.

В вашем случае варианта два.

1. отказаться от использования производных форм и писать каждую форму отдельно и самостоятельно. Ну или копи-пастом.
2. создать минимальную базовую форму которая будет содержать только общие для всех других форм элементы, а частности уже реализовывать в производных.

Выбор варианта за вами, но второй предпочтительнее.

---

Небольшое замечание, для вашей цели удобнее создавать не отдельные формы для каждого игрового экрана, а создать для этого отдельные контролы, которые будут отображаться в определенном порядке. Посмотрите в сторону использования `UserControl` в качестве основы для игровых экранов.